# Optimum way of getting LatLngBound from a list of LatLng in Kotlin

Tags: google-maps, kotlin

I'm trying to get the `LatLngBound` from a list of `LatLng`.

```
        val latLngs: List<LatLng> = placeList.map { LatLng(it.placeLat, it.placeLon) }

        val latLngBound = LatLngBounds(
                LatLng(latLngs.minBy { it.latitude }?.latitude ?: DEFAULT_LAT,
                        latLngs.minBy { it.longitude }?.longitude ?: DEFAULT_LAT),
                LatLng(latLngs.maxBy { it.latitude }?.latitude ?: DEFAULT_LNG,
                        latLngs.maxBy { it.longitude }?.longitude ?: DEFAULT_LNG))
```

I'm getting it as above approach, where getting the minimum Lat and Lng, and follow by Max Lat and Lng. Is there a better way to get it then manually search for maximum and minimum as above (and Kotlin provided collection function)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`LatLngBounds.Builder`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.Builder)

```
val latLngBound = latLngs.fold ( LatLngBounds.builder(), { builder, it -> builder.include(it) } ).build()
```

Comment: Nice one @leonardkraemer

Comment: perfect. Worked like a charm.